# How to initialize an NSObject's subclass on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, initialization, class-design, subclass

I want to write some methods in a class so that other classes can call these methods  using `[instance methodName:Parameter]`.

If the class is a subclass of `UIViewController`, I can use `initWithNibName` to initialize it. But I want to write the methods in an **NSObject's** subclass, how can I initialize it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I find this may work:

```
TheClass *newObject = [[TheClass alloc] init];
//do something here
[newObject release];
```

Comment: That is simply initializing the object "newObject" as a TheClass class. If TheClass doesn't implement "- (id)init" with "[super init]" and "return self;", your initialization will likely fail.

Answer (score 57):

iphony is correct, but he or she doesn't say that you need to write the init method yourself. Your init method should generally look something like this:

```
- (id) init
    {
    if (self = [super init])
         {
         myMember1 = 0; // do your own initialisation here
         myMember2 = 0;
         }
    return self;
    }
```

Although the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/init) says

> The init method defined in the NSObject class does no initialization; it simply returns self.

and one can just be tempted to write

```
- (id) init
  {
    myMember1 = 0; // do your own initialisation here
    myMember2 = 0;
    return self;
  }
```

this is WRONG and not following what is explicitly stated in documentation:

> In a custom implementation of this (init) method, you must invoke super’s
> designated initializer then initialize and return the new object.

MUST. Not should, could, ought to, etc.

You should not assume NSObject's init does not change in future; nor the superclass from which your custom class derives.

Comment: is [super init] necessary? because the documentation of NSObject's init method says otherwise.

Comment: One should never omit super init! Even if it does nothing. The docs say explicitly: "In a custom implementation of this method, you must invoke super’s designated initializer then initialize and return the new object." I've edited the answer.